# sql file parameter and template

Tags: delphi

while working with SQL and databases I use SQl statements, like **"select * from Mytablename"**
I store the short statement in a text file. Is there any build in function in DELPHI which allows me to replace the word **"myTablename**" by the real value I must use on the concrete query ?

Guess there are many params / strings I want to exchange from the sql template to the real SQL statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringReplace('select * from Mytablename','Mytablename','NewTablename',[])
```